# How to configure email plugin and send email in guidewire

Tags: guidewire

How do we configure email plugin in guidewire so that email can be sent. I have seen EmailUtil class which have method sendEmailWithBody, but its not sending email and neither giving any exception. Can somebody help me?

I have tried configuring email plugin, also tried using EmailUtil, but notjing seems to work. I am not what I am missing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should review **emailBessageTransport.gwp**.

In Guidewire, emails are sent asynchronously using the Guidewire messaging system. This means that when you invoke *EmailUtil.sendEmailWithBody*, a message is placed onto the Email Message Queue (ID 65).

The OOTB message queue uses parameters from **emailMessageTransport.gwp** to establish a connection with the SMTP server and OOTB it has dummy values.

For more information on email functionality in Guidewire apps, please refer to "Guidewire ClaimCenter and email" or "Guidewire PolicyCenter and email" articles on https://docs.guidewire.com.

Answer (score 5):

With Guidewire Cloud, you are no longer able to send email from Guidewire Insurance Suite xCenters.  Standard IS-INT-1312 "Use of SMTP" once disallowed the usage of SMTP, but that standard has been retired as of 2023.02.  The SMTP ports are now blocked in your AWS environments so email is no longer possible from an xCenter.

The new standard IS-INT-1335 "Use of Guidewire Integration Framework" was published in 2023.8 (for Hakuba update) and provides the new guidance for SMTP:

> Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP) -
> Integration Gateway can be used to send email using the Apache Camel Mail component. The customer is responsible for providing the SMTP server, and all communication must be secured in accordance with Guidewire Cloud Security standards.

Please reference the standard here (as of Hakuba): https://docs.guidewire.com/cloud/standards/latest/Integration/Standard-IS-INT-1335-UseOfGuidewireIntegrationFramework.html?hl=smtp
(you may be required to log-in).  Note that standards are subject to change so make sure you are reviewing the latest version of the standards.

Even if you are using an on-premises installation, I would recommend you consider switching to Integration Gateway or an alternate email configuration.